# slow cheetah xml transformation tool is overwritting the original config

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, connection-string, transformation, slowcheetah

I am using slow cheetah web config transformation tool for transforming connection-string.config according to deployment settings. Problem is after transformation it overwrites the original ConnectionString in solution to the transformed config as well. Any idea what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of this before but haven't been able to figure out what is happening here. I think this may be specific to some particular environment config.

If you are impacted by this, you could help me figure this out by commenting below with the following info.

1. OS version
2. Visual Studio version
3. Is your home drive mapped to a network share
4. Anything unusual about your machine setup?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I am really struggling to fix this. Currently, I am running Windows 7 enterprise edition, visual studio 2010  premium, and deploying locally on a machine. Nothing unusual comes in my mind. thanks

Comment: Still waiting for the feed back

Comment: Still haven't been able to repro it. I just heard a hint as to what it could be today. A machine which doesn't have 4.5 installed. I am setting up a VM to repro it. Do u have 4.5 installed?

Comment: @Sayed - I can confirm we're seeing this behaviour too,  it works perfectly on my machine but two of my colleagues are seeing the original config being overwritten. We're all using `VS 2010 Ultimate 10.0.40219.1.SP1Rel` and the exact same code base.  We're of the opinion there must be something environmental occurring, but have been unable to track down exactly what.

Comment: @Sayed - Well it turns out I had .net 4.5 installed and my colleagues didn't.  Upgrading solved the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and solved it by changing the following code directly inside the .csproj file:

```
<Content Include="Web.config">
  <TransformOnBuild>false</TransformOnBuild>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
```

I've changed the setting `TransormOnBuild` to `false`. When deploying, it still uses the transformed Web.config file (tested with File System deployment type).

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you've got .NET version **4.0** installed.  When upgrading to **4.5** the issue has disappeared completely.